# C# chart data won't display

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, charts, windows-forms-designer

Hi I'm writing a Windows Form App in C # under VS 2010.
I'm trying to implement a chart and used the following code to display data in the chart:

```
for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
chart1.Series["Val"].Points.AddXY(i, his[i]);
}
```

his[i] is an integer array. My problem is the chart area is just blank.
The code compiles totally fine, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Any idea ?

EDIT:

I found out that the chart does show up, but I have to minimize my program than again
otherwise it won't show. Any one know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, just have to type

```
Refresh();
```

after setting points on the chart.

Comment: Thx though stackoverflow won't let you mark your own answer as the correct one until 2 days have passed :)